# belongsTo vs hasMany in sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

Let say we have shirt table and jhon table.

in sequelize when we use `db.jhon.hasMany(db.shirt)` ,

then it create the foriegn key in the shirt table
 and we use `db.shirt.belongsTo(db.jhon)` ,
 it create foriegn key of jhon  in the shirt table.

So the taregt and source are just changing of foreign key . Is there are any more diffrence to diffrenciate these keywords `hasMany` and `belongsTo`

What it is ? why and when to use ??

Any help would appriciated !!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you read original doc about this?
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/

There are several useful examples about this...

It's about:

1. Your domain model
2. About usage `include` in your query

Just read about this relations in SQL in general 
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/152731/what-is-the-main-difference-between-has-many-and-belongs-to-relationship-in-mysq